# WooCommerce how to customise the default content of the displayed order field?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm able to add a new admin order list column but don't know how to alter or format the content display for the order column.

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'MY_COLUMNS_FUNCTION' );
function MY_COLUMNS_FUNCTION( $columns ) {
    $new_columns = ( is_array( $columns ) ) ? $columns : array();
    $new_columns['MY_COLUMN_ID_1'] = 'Payment';
    return $new_columns;
}
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'MY_COLUMNS_VALUES_FUNCTION', 10,2 );
function MY_COLUMNS_VALUES_FUNCTION( $column ) {
global $post;
if ( $column === 'order_number' ) { echo $post->ID;}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
add_filter('manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'webtoffee_alter_order_columns');

function webtoffee_alter_order_columns($columns) {

    $new_columns = ( is_array($columns) ) ? $columns : array();

    unset($new_columns['order_number']);

    $res_array = array_slice($new_columns, 0, 1, true) + array("custom_order_number" => "Order Number") +  array_slice($new_columns, 1, count($new_columns)-1, true);

    return $res_array;
}

add_action('manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'webtoffee_alter_order_number_columns', 10, 2);

function webtoffee_alter_order_number_columns($column) {

    global $post, $woocommerce, $the_order;

    if ($column === 'custom_order_number') {
        // do your stuff
    }
}
```

Try this sample to modify

Comment: mujuonly, Thanks for you help I have tried to put your code and it works as expected but the problem is the result is placed in front of the default value (order no. link)!!!  Any suggestion?

Comment: Either you can unset the existing column and add a column with the code you used in OP and do your things or you can modify the buyer name with this filter woocommerce_admin_order_buyer_name

Comment: Ok, I get it.

add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_buyer_name', 'my_custom_buyername',10,2);
function my_custom_buyername( $column ) {
    global $post, $woocommerce, $the_order;
    echo "test";
}

But The Order No. Link still exist!   Do you know how to remove it?  thanks again.

Comment: mujuonly, One more thing that I wish to implement , when I replaced the default column with your code, it works find except when resizing the browser it is not responsive like the default behaviour!! I noticed that the customised column header has no "column-primary" class! Do you have experienced with this issue?

Comment: I mean when I do inspect the header title element in the customised column with chrome it should have "column-primary" style!! while the new one not have that why the responsive is broke??  right?

Comment: Ok, trying to fix it!  Thanks